# os-prober returns nothing

Tags: grub2

What does it mean if os-prober returns nothing.

I understood that this should find all my installed operating systems. But I'm running from ubuntu so I expected it to at least find that. But I get no output at all.

sudo fdisk -l gives

```
Disk /dev/sda: 40.0 GB, 40020664320 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4865 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00067959

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        4680    37590016   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            4680        4866     1489921    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            4680        4866     1489920   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo os-prober`.

Comment: @arrange - the question has the output of sudo os-prober (nothing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `os-prober` script is meant to find **other** operating systems than the mounted root system. As you don't have any of these (*swap* isn't an operating system), `os-prober` returns nothing.

To populate the grub menu use the `sudo update-grub` command. This will include the mounted partitions too.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Made "sudo update-grub", generating grub configuration files... Then os-prober with another OS in another partition that was found before. And nothing is shown.